# Predefined views and result limiting

Tags: python, couchdb

I previously asked a question here at stackoverflow about how to limit results, using temporary (JavaScript) functions. But, since I got no answer, I have to switch to predefined views. Scanning several pages in google, the only example I found is this one:

```
def fun(doc):
    if "name" in doc:
        yield doc['name'], None
```

But, unfortunately, the demonstration of this view is not accompanied by an example of its usage. So, how does one actually use views to query results in `CouchDb`, and, no less important, how does one limit results. In `SQL` world I would formulate my query like `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE FIELD1 = "VALUE" LIMIT 1`. How to implement the similar thing in `CouchDb`?

PS. I know documentation exists and possibly at some page there is an answer. But I it's hard to find. And besides I feel a lack of tiny simple examples like `SELECT ... WHERE ... LIMIT ...`.

**EDIT**

This [documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/py-couchdb/latest/py-couchdb.pdf) in section `2.3` also gives an example of view, but does not give an example of its usage. So, if there is anybody in the world, who actually knows how to use views in `CouchDB`? The sole knowledge of views existance is not useful at all.

Answer (score 0):

You also have the `?limit=` as query parameter available.

There are a bunch of other useful parameters: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/ddoc/views.html